# Do measures preserves inequalities?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $\mu: \Sigma \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a signed Radon measure and $\lambda : \Sigma \to [0,+\infty]$ a positive Radon measure, where $\Sigma$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology of the real line, denoted by $\tau$. Write $\mu = \mu^+ - \mu^-$ and suppose that

$$
|\mu(A)| \le \lambda (A), \quad \forall A \in \tau
$$

Using this, is it possible to prove that $|\mu(A)| \le \lambda(A)$ for every measurable set $A \in \Sigma$?

[Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniqueness_of_Measures) in this link, there is a proof for the case where $\mu$ is positive and there is equality rather than inequality.

Comment: Try using the fact that Radon measures admit approximations by open subsets, i.e, $\mu(A) = \inf \{ \mu(O) \ \vert \ A \subset O, O \in \tau\}$